# Can my mum sponsor my trip (tourist visa ) UK

Tags: uk, tourist-visas, visa-sponsors

I have been refused entry into the UK twice thus on a tourist visa with my own bank statement.(insufficient funds) and that they doubt the bank account doesn’t reflect my true expenditures.

The question now is can my mum sponsor my trip to the UK on a tourist visa even though I’m above 18 and a student in Ghana?

Comment: Is your mother in the UK and a UK resident?

Comment: Please upload a copy of the refusal letters with personal information blanked out.

Answer (score 4):

**Yes your mother can sponsor your trip.**

She would have to include a letter saying she will pay your expenses, and also her own bank statements showing that she is rich enough that giving you money for a tourist trip is not a problem for her. [Details can be found here](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/827480/Visit-guidance-v9.0ext.pdf#page21). (Thanks Traveller)

You should also be aware that you have to address the issue of you bank statement not reflecting your true expenditures. Without addressing this it will not help to have someone sponsor you.  See other questions on this site and [this guidance](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules) for how to address this problem.

You should be aware that after two refusals it becomes increasingly difficult for you to be accepted even when you address the issues. Repeated applications after refusals make it look like you are desperate to get to the UK, which makes them think you have some reason other than tourism.

You might want to consider visiting a country other than the UK for your tourism.

Comment: @Owen FWIW, the Immigration Rule allowing a 3rd party to provide maintenance and accommodation support is explained here https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/827480/Visit-guidance-v9.0ext.pdf#page21 However, as DJClayworth mentions in their answer, having a sponsor does not mean that previous refusals will not be taken into account. Your application will still need to demonstrate that you meet the eligibility requirements in V4 of the Rules https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules